# How can I catch an attempt to focus on a hidden object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a jquery extensions that hides my select-elements and adds custom markup instead. This is so that I can style the elements and perform some custom behvaiour(like adding images to the items)

This is what the markup will look like in a simple example:

```
<select id="original" style="display:none"><option value="1">1</option><select>
<ul id="new" class="select">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

I also use another jquery-extension to validate forms. If a field is invalid, it attempts to focus that field. Browsers won't allow focusing on hidden fields. This is a problem mainly because if the field isn't focused, the browser won't scroll to where the invalid field is.

My dream-solution would be to add a listener for attempts to focus the select-element, but I can't use a normal `$('parent').on('focus', "#original ...)`, because the events don't trigger on `display:none`-objects. I have also considered hiding the element some other way, but atleast `visbility: hidden` won't allow focus either.

How can I focus either the original or the new element? When an attempt to focus the original element is made?

Comment: Semantically (and logically), it is impossible to focus something that is not visible. Maybe you should try a completely different approach, maybe, not to scroll to the input but scroll to its paragraph/section. Or put some kind of `if` before the *attempt* to check for the elements visibility.

Comment: Sure, and that's fine, I could focus #new which is visible. But what event can trigger that focus?

Comment: opacity:0 can help? but the difference is that invisible elements vs undisplayed elements  take space on the page

Comment: @G-Host, this seems to work, but only if the element has height > 0

Comment: @KristofferNolgren of course, if u want the transparent element to not have impact in your page you have to wrap it in with a relative element and make it absolute positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried adding all possible events to the element, document, and window.  Nothing gets triggered when attempting focus on a hidden element.

I've come up with a work-around:

1. Add an off-screen input and a hidden class:
   **HTML:** `<input id="I0">`
   **CSS:** `#I0, .hidden {position: absolute; left: -999px;}`
2. Include that input at the beginning of all focus calls:
   `$('#I0, #Name').focus();`
3. Add this code:

---

```
$('input, select').focus(function() {
  if($(this).data('invisible')) {
    //this will be run if the element is hidden
  }

  $('input, select').each(function() {
    $(this).data('invisible', !$(this).is(':visible'));
    if($(this).data('invisible')) {
      $(this)
        .show()
        .addClass('hidden');
      (function(self) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          self
            .hide()
            .removeClass('hidden');
        },0);
      })($(this));
    }
  });

});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cutffd6j/)

Comment: That's a great effort! I did a variation on this. I hid the element by setting opacity: 0, position: absolute and adding postion relative to the wrapping element. This also hid the element and made it take up zero space.